# Dependency injection in ASP.NET WebAPI: IHttpControllerActivator vs. IDependencyResolver

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

Recently I came across this discussion.

In ASP.NET WebAPI, when we need to integrate a custom inversion of control/dependency injection container, we need to go with two different strategies:

1. Implement `IHttpControllerActivator`, which is an extension point to fully control controller's life-cycle. That is, we can define how a controller is instantiated. At this point, we can *resolve* the controller using an inversion of control container and let it use its own dependency injection approach.
2. Implement `IDependencyResolver`, where we can define how to resolve dependency injections.

In my current projects I went the `IHttpControllerActivator` way, and since I'm using *Castle Windsor* as inversion of control container, I can fully control object life cycle from its container configuration, and I can decide how controllers are resolved, and the scope of its recursively-injected dependencies defining that **they die once the controller ends its life (i.e. when the request ends)**.

While some of these features can be achieved with `IDependencyResolver` implementations, I feel that `IHttpControllerActivator` is the best way to integrate inversion of control and dependency injection in ASP.NET Web API, because I believe that I prefer to stay as abstract as possible and stick with Castle Windsor configuration model in terms of inversion of control and dependency injection.

The main drawback with the `IHttpControllerActivator` approach is you need to register all controllers in the container while `IDependencyResolver` still gives the responsibility of resolving the controller to ASP.NET Web API pipeline (*for me, this hasn't been a big issue, I just used Castle Windsor's `Classes.FromAssembly` to configure all controllers deriving `ApiController`*).

**Do I ignore any other drawbacks that would make the `IDependencyResolver` approach more appropiate?**

Comment: The need to resolve all controllers from Castle is the only drawback you stated. Which other drawbacks should be discussed in the answers?

Comment: @Steven The ones I might be ignoring. It's just to know if going this route is worse than going the `IDependencyResolver` route or it's just a subjective decision.

Comment: I think that going through the `IHttpControllerActivator` is the right way to go. This holds for MVC, Web API and the new ASP.NET Core framework.

Comment: @Steven What has driven me to this question is I'm performing a DDD with WebAPI course and one of my attenders asked me: isn't over-engineering going the `IHttpControllerActivator` route? And I said him: if you can transfer the responsibility of the entire object graph to the inversion of control container, you get more flexibility, control and features than reducing Castle Windsor to just a dependency injector.

Comment: @Steven Since an `IDependencyResolver` can also inject dependencies on controller's constructor, that attender thought: why I need to configure my controllers on Castle Windsor and why not leaving default WebAPI controller resolver instantiate the whole controller?

Comment: @Steven And I answered: I would use `IDependencyResolver` to inject dependencies on controllers' actions since you wouldn't be able to do so with just implementing an `IHttpControllerActivator` because Castle Windsor has constructor and property injection only (it's not responsible of calling methods on arbitrary types...).

Comment: The problem with the `IDependencyResolver` interface is that it is too generic and forces a consumer to return `null` if a service can't be resolved (instead of throwing an exception). This is why there are hundreds of questions here on SO about the "controllers should have a default constructor" exception message. Implementing the `IHttpControllerActivator` solves this problem, because its contract does not allow returning `null`.

Comment: Here's an article by Mark Seeman on the subject.  http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/09/28/DependencyInjectionandLifetimeManagementwithASP.NETWebAPI/
He lays out the issues of using IDependencyResolver and why IHttpControllerActivator is better.

Comment: @Fran Very interesting article

Comment: It would be great to add an answer summarizing the pros and cons of both approaches and mark it as *community wiki*

Answer (score 3):

The `IHttpControllerActivator` approach primarily has an advantage over the `IDependencyResolver` approach because of the context provided, as excellently described in the following blog post: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/09/28/DependencyInjectionandLifetimeManagementwithASP.NETWebAPI/.

However, in most easier scenarios, it simply does not pay back the extra effort to manually register everything. Using the IDependencyResolver approach in many situations just 'does the trick'. Add good documentation and the larger day to day user base to that, and I myself would probably consider if I could manage using `IDependencyResolver` before considering `IHttpControllerActivator`.